# Using linguex, how can I change the spacing between subexamples?

Tags: linguistics, linguex

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\ex.
  \ag.
    Dette er ein test paa nynorsk.\\
    This is a test in Nynorsk\\
    \trans `This is a test in Nynorsk.'
  \bg.
    Dies ist ein Test auf Deutsch.\\
    This is a test in German\\
    \trans `This is a test in German.'

\end{document}
```

Its output looks like this:

[image: LaTeX example output]

Is there a way to increase the spacing between subexample (a) and subexample (b) (i.e. increasing the vertical space between "This is a test in Nynorsk." and "Dies ist ein Test auf Deutsch.")? Sometimes I have some kind of logical structure between the glossing and the actual translation, and if there is no spacing between subexamples that consist of four (or more lines), they become very clumsy to read very quickly.

Among other things, I had a look at the `linguex` documentation (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/linguex/linguex-doc.pdf), which mentions a number of "lengths and margins" that can be customised (6f.), but I could not find anything that would correspond to the parameter I would like to change.

Comment: if my answer was helpful for you, please upvote with the arrow up on the left hand side. If it could solve your problem, please mark it as solution with the tick below. THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just use `\vspace{xpt}`

e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
    \ex.
    \ag.
    Dette er ein test paa nynorsk.\\
    This is a test in Nynorsk\\
    \trans `This is a test in Nynorsk.'
    \vspace{1cm}\bg.
    Dies ist ein Test auf Deutsch.\\
    This is a test in German\\
    \trans `This is a test in German.'

\end{document}
```

[image: linguex]

I also couldn't find an option to set vertical space. These margins you were talking about on page 6 were horizontal margins only.

Comment: I fear I will have to do it that way manually then, thanks. I can't upvote yet because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than do this manually, it's better to patch the subexample macro to add as much vertical space as you need automatically. I've used `.66\baselineskip` as the extra vertical space which matches what `linguex` value for `Extopsep`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength{\SubItemSkip}
\setlength{\SubItemSkip}{.66\baselineskip}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\a}{\itemsep\z@}{\itemsep\SubItemSkip}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ex.
  \ag.
    Dette er ein test paa nynorsk.\\
    This is a test in Nynorsk\\
    \trans `This is a test in Nynorsk.'
  \bg.
    Dies ist ein Test auf Deutsch.\\
    This is a test in German\\
    \trans `This is a test in German.'
  \c. An single example.
  \c. Another example.

\ex. An example.

\ex. Another example.

\end{document}
```

This code changes the spacing of *all* subexamples. If this is not what you want, but you would prefer just to have extra spacing after the glossed examples, then you can redefine the `\glt` and the `\trans` commands (the latter being a an alias for the former.)  To do this, replace the `\patchcommand` line and instead use:

```
\def\glt#1{\vspace{.17\baselineskip}#1\vspace{\SubItemSkip}}
\let\trans\glt
```

This will add extra vertical space only after `\trans` lines but not after single subexamples, or glossed examples without a translation.

[image: output of code]