# Using Philex how can I change the spacing between subexamples?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, linguistics, linguex

Please, can someone explain how to patch Philex to customize the spacing between examples, subexamples and subsubexamples, **respectively**.

For example, if I want spacing between subexamples but no spacing between subsubexamples, and if I want even more spacing between examples than between subexamples.

Related page :
[Using linguex, how can I change the spacing between subexamples?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294663/using-linguex-how-can-i-change-the-spacing-between-subexamples)

MWE :

```
  \documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
    \usepackage{philex}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \newlength{\SubItemSkip}
    \setlength{\SubItemSkip}{.66\baselineskip}
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\a}{\itemsep\z@}{\itemsep\SubItemSkip}{}{}
    \makeatother
    
    
\begin{document}
    
    \lb{tests}{
        \lba{inforx}{Possible modification by `in/for \textit{x} time'.}
        \lbb{fc}{Possible modification by \textit{frequent}/\textit{constant}.}
        \lbb{control}{Possible Implicit Agent Control.}
        \lbz{byp}{\textit{By}-phrases and, when available, possessives realize arguments.}}
    
    
    \lb{examples}{
        \lba{inforx-ex}{
            \lba{inx-ex}{La destruction de la ville par l'armée en quelques heures nous a stupéfaits.}
            \lbz{forx-ex}{Le chef de service a ordonné la surveillance du patient par les internes durant plusieurs jours.}}}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to show a compilable `philex` example that shows what you're doing. It seems likely that the solution I gave in the linked answer could be made to work but I know nothing about `philex`.

Comment: In fact, pasting the preamble code in my answer into a `philex` document seems to do what you want. If that's not what you want then explain what the problem is.

Comment: As I said, I'd like to differentiate between examples, subexamples and subsubexamples. I added a MWE. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry but your example doesn't help me understand where you want the extra space.

Comment: I don't have a definitive idea, but for example if I want spacing between subexamples but no spacing between subsubexamples, and if I want even more spacing between examples than between subexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that allows you to set both the `\topsep` and the `\itemsep` values for the sub- and subsub-examples. The spacing between examples at the top level is simply a new paragraph, so there's no way to set that spacing; you can add `\medskip` or `bigskip` between examples if you need to. In this sample code, I've set different values for each one; it probably makes sense to have identical `\topsep` and `\itemsep` values for any one level, however.

Since this code only modifies `linguex` code, it will work equally well for `linguex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{philex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength{\lngxtopsepii}
\setlength{\lngxtopsepii}{10pt}% linguex uses .3\Extopsep by default
\newlength{\lngxtopsepiii}
\setlength{\lngxtopsepiii}{5pt}
\newlength{\lngxitemsepii}
\setlength{\lngxitemsepii}{10pt}
\newlength{\lngxitemsepiii}
\setlength{\lngxitemsepiii}{5pt}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\a}{\ifnum\theExDepth=2\topsep .3\Extopsep\else\topsep 0pt\fi 
     \parsep\z@\itemsep\z@}
     {\ifnum\theExDepth>1\topsep\csname lngxtopsep\roman{ExDepth}\endcsname
     \itemsep\csname lngxitemsep\roman{ExDepth}\endcsname\else\topsep\z@\itemsep\z@\fi
     \parsep\z@}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lbp{clauses}{PP}{Some main words, followed by
\lba{first}{Time flies
\lba{firstnew}{Like an arrow}
\lbz{lastnew}{And much too fast}}
\lbb{second}{But never stops}
\lbz{last}{Which is lucky}
and a concluding comment.}

\medskip
\lbp{clauses}{PP}{Some main words, followed by
\lba{first}{Time flies
\lba{firstnew}{Like an arrow}
\lbz{lastnew}{And much too fast}}
\lbb{second}{But never stops}
\lbz{last}{Which is lucky}
and a concluding comment.}


\end{document}
```

### Code explantion

The main example command in `linguex` is the `\a` macro, which sets up the `\list` environment that underlies the example. So we use the patching facilities of the `etoolbox` package to modify the definition of `\a`. The `\patchcmd` macro takes four arguments: the part of the original macro to be replaced, the replacement, and two arguments for  "patch successful" and "patch unsuccessful". As long as we know the patch will work then these can safely be left empty.

So in the specific example here, I have replaced the `linguex` code that sets the `\topsep` and `\itemsep` of the list to code that sets the values dependent on the level of the list. I've named the lengths used with `ii` and `iii` suffixes so that I can construct the value from the list depth value using `\roman{ExDepth}`.

### Output

[image: output of code]

Comment: Amazing, you are the best, Alan.

Comment: @Vincent I've added some explanation of the code.

Comment: Ah ok ! So \roman{ExDepth} actually corresponds to the "ii" and "iii" suffixes added at the end of the "\lngxitemsep" and "\lngxtopsep" command names, and this is what lngxitemsep\roman{ExDepth} and lngxtopsep\roman{ExDepth} do , i.e. as arguments of \csname they define the suffixed command names ! Which is very flexible since it theoretically allows for deeper levels (within the limits inherent to the package, of course...)

Comment: @Vincent Yes, this is correct. Although the kernel supports nesting up to 5 levels, `linguex` itself only defines labels up to 2 levels, so it's not practically extendable.

Comment: And for the space between the label and the sentence, this is :
\SubExLeftmargin and \SubSubExleftmargin (thanks to frabjous as he kindly answered here
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638271/262813).