# Space between label and subexample with Linguex

Tags: linguex

I cannot increase the horizontal spacing between the label and the subexample, which is problematic with large grammaticality judgments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\Exlabelsep}{3em}
\setlength{\Exlabelwidth}{2em}

\ex. Main level
\a. Sublevel
\a. Subsublevel1
\b. Subsublevel 2
\b. **Subsublevel 3

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lengths you're looking for are `\SubExleftmargin` and `\SubSubExleftmargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\Exlabelsep}{3em}
\setlength{\Exlabelwidth}{2em}
\setlength{\SubExleftmargin}{3em}
\setlength{\SubSubExleftmargin}{3em}

\ex. Main level
\a. Sublevel
\a. Subsublevel1
\b. Subsublevel 2
\b. **Subsublevel 3

\end{document}
```

[image: linguex example]